# Appending all ancestors of a binary tree node to a String in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am writing a family tree program in Java using a binary tree. The ancestors method is called from another class and calls findAncestors to run recursively to append ALL ancestors to an output String. I added parent pointers to my tree in hopes of making finding all ancestors easier.

The locate method I use searches the tree for the passed String and returns the Node in which it is located.

The issue I am currently having is the method is returning with only the direct parent instead of all ancestors of the node.

```
public String ancestors(String x)
    {
    String outputString = "";
    if (locate(x).parent!=null)
        outputString = findAncestors(locate(x),outputString);
    return outputString;
    }

    private String findAncestors(Node x,String outputString)
    {
    if(x.parent != null)
        {
            outputString = outputString + String.valueOf(x.parent.value);
            findAncestors(x.parent,outputString);
        }
    return outputString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot past the string as a changing-parameter bcause it's immutable.
try:

```
  return findAncestors(x.parent,outputString);
```

Comment: Bah, you're right! I missed that staring me right in the face. Thanks.